# Hive query to get min and max of date column group by year and id

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, hive, hiveql

I have table with two columns ,id and date.I want to get the max and min dates for that particular id as per that year. Below is the sample data and the result I wanted 
Sample Data

```
id  date_col

123 2015-05-01 04:00:00

123 2017-04-01 04:00:00

123 2017-09-01 04:00:00

123 2014-09-01 04:00:00

123 2012-12-01 05:00:00

123 2016-08-01 04:00:00

123 2014-05-01 04:00:00

123 2016-10-01 04:00:00
```

Results I am expecting

```
123 2014-05-01   2014-09-01

123 2015-05-01

123 2016-08-01   2016-10-01

123 2017-04-01   2017-09-01
```

I tried by using below multiple query but i won't be sorting according to the year

```
SELECT id,MAX(date_col) AS maxdate_col,MIN(date_col) AS mindate_col FROM table GROUP BY id 

SELECT id,MAX(date_col) AS max_votes,MIN(date_col) AS mindate_col,YEAR(date_col) FROM test GROUP BY id,YEAR(date_col)
```

Comment: what is the output of your second query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT id
        ,MIN(date_col) AS mindate_col
        ,(CASE WHEN MAX(date_col) <> MIN(date_col) THEN MAX(date_col) END)  AS maxdate_col
        ,YEAR(date_col) AS year_col
FROM    test 
GROUP BY id,YEAR(date_col)
ORDER BY id,year_col
```

If you want only the `date` part, you can cast it `CAST(date_col AS DATE)`